# Exporting Tabstat in Stata

Tags: statistics, stata, summary

I am trying to export tabstat result from stata. I am using following commands.

```
estpost tabstat x1 x2 x3 x4, by(country)
estout using Data\summary.csv
```

However, when I open the CSV file, I only find

```
country
b
```

in the CSV file. Please let me know if there is something wrong in the commands I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Answer coming from:
http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/estpost.html#estpost101b

```
by country: eststo: quietly estpost summarize x1 x2 x3 x4, listwise
esttab using summary.csv, cells("mean") label nodepvar
```

You can add different summary stats to `cells`, for example: `cells("mean sd min max")` would show the mean, standard deviation, minimum, and maximum for each x in each country.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
eststo X : qui estpost tabstat x1 x2 x3 x4 , by(country) stats(mean) 
esttab X using summary.csv , cells("x1 x2 x3 x4") plain nomtitle nonumber noobs
```

The `plain` option is supposed to get convert the annoying `="0.143"` to `0.145` in your output according to the documentation but it is not working for me.

You can use the output format `xls` instead, but then it prints all values in the same cell with five spaces between most but not the first two numbers of each line.

As in so many cases, you are better off saving your dataset and reading it into python with `pd.read_stata()` and then solving the problem there. Nowadays you can even call Python from within Stata, although that path leads to the dark side...